# IPC interprocess communication between different .c files

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I cannot give code right now since I am currently working on the idea in my head and messing around on the internet.

I have learned about interprocess communication and using shared memory to share data (structs specifically) between processes.

However, I am confused about how to share data with a process after using fork() and execv( ...) on a program that is held in a different .c file.

If we give the semaphore key as an argument to the other program (which becomes a child process), will we be able to access the shared memory with a semget?

Comment: Are you aware that different `.c` files or a single big `.c` file hold almost no difference once the program is compiled?

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

1. Depending upon implementation, Single or Multiple source file(s), `.c` in your case can constitute to a single executable. A single executable runs a process. If the source has a `fork()` done in the code, then the child process is created. So, your

   > ...interprocess communication between different .c files

   need not be necessarily two `.c` files, irrespective if they are compiled as a single project or two different projects.
2. To keep it simple say, you have two different source files, one of them should create a shared memory.

   ```
   #define SHMSPACE    35
   char *shm, *str;
   key_t key = 1234;

   //Create a memory segment to be shared
   if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSPACE, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
   {
       perror("shmget failed");
       exit(1);
   }

   //Attach the segment to memory space.
   if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
   {
       perror("shmat failed");
       exit(1);
   }

   //Write something like A to Z in the shared memory for other process to read
   str = shm;
   for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) //c is declared as an int somewhere above.
       *str++ = c;
   *str = NULL;
   ```

   You other source should be:

   ```
   #define SHMSPACE    35
   char *shm, *str;
   key_t key = 1234;

   //Get the shared memory segment
   if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSPACE, 0666)) < 0)
   {
       perror("shmget failed");
       exit(1);
   }

   //Attach the segment to our data space.
   if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
   {
       perror("shmat");
       exit(1);
   }

   //Read what other process has put in the memory.
   for (str = shm; *str != NULL; s++)
       putchar(*str);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that by saying "two different C files " you mean "two different processes (ie two C files with main() in them)".

To solve this you can use shared memory spaces. You may use shm_open to create a memory space using a name. The name is the unique identifier for this space. You can also pass `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` as arguments to the shm_open function. This allows you to define that the space is to be created, and it is exclusive (ie the space does not already exist). The return of the shm_open function is a file descriptor.

Hence the first thread can map it as Exclusive, and the second thread can drop the O_EXCL argument to map it as existing. Hence you now have a memory space that the processes can use.

To use it, you must map the space to both processes memory space. Assuming you have a structure you wish to use to pass data between the processes.

You begin by truncating the size of the file specified by the file descriptor. Hence you use `ftruncate(shm_file_descriptor, sizeof(struct shm_structure))`
Once it is of the appropriate size, you can use mmap to map it to the appropriate size.

```
shmp = mmap(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

You can now access the shared memory space as such `shmp->first_field`.

Where :

```
struct shm_struct { uint8_t first_field;};
```

You now have a shared memory space, which belongs to two processes(assuming you've created and mapped the space to both processes). You have to decide how to control access to this space. A simple method would be to add a control system(mutex, semaphore, the like), which allows only one process to read/write to the space at any one time. The control will be written by you essentially. You will have to check that you have obtained the lock before you read/write.

There are many methods by which you can achieve this control mechanism.